# Drawing a triangle in a 2-dimensional char array

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array, char, geometry

I'm trying to use a 2d char array as sort of a table for shapes and I'm having trouble trying to draw a triangle. Given the position of the top of the triangle and its height, my function is supposed to draw a triangle in a 25-row, 80-column char array by changing its elements that I've already assigned to ' ' initially.This is what I have so far:

```
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<height; i++){
    for(j=-i; j<=i; j++){
        screen[x+i][y+j]=ch;
    }
}
```

screen is the name of my 2d char array.

for example it should be like this for a triangle of height 3 :

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

but it doesn't seem to work for some reason and I can't see why.

I apologize for not clarifying what my code does as it is.
I have the below function to print my 2d array :

```
void PrintScreen(){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SCREEN_WIDTH; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", screen[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
} // end-PrintScreen
```

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I couldn't see anything I ran the program before because of a mistake I made. If anyone else needs help with the same problem, the code above should work fine.

Comment: What's your code drawing at the moment?

Comment: How do you allocate and initialize `screen` array? Better post complete example.

Comment: `" If anyone else needs help with the same problem, the code above should work fine."` no one even knows what was the problem and the code above is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This minimalist example condensed from your snippets works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 25
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 80

char screen[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int height = 10;
    int x = 1, y = 10;

    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(j=-i; j<=i; j++){
            screen[x+i][y+j]='*';
        }
    }    

    for(i=0; i<SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<SCREEN_WIDTH; j++) {
            printf("%c", screen[i][j]==0 ? ' ' : '*');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

But your x and y axes seem reversed. X usually goes left-right and Y - up-down.